# Drupal site URL

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I am currently working to an application that needs the site's Url of a Drupal installation in a web server. As far I am concerned Drupal provides the variable $base_url in the settings.php file that is however optional for the developer to fill  it.I can imagine that they have a mechanism that auto detects base url but this mechanism under specific circumstances can fail and cause different kind of errors (This is the explanation for the optional character of $live_site variable in Joomla). So under which circumstances an installation in  a public or private web server with empty $base_url variable faces problems and what kind of ?

Comment: Why are you not using $_SERVER PHP variable?

Comment: Yes this a possible solution but for another case as I have only access to the installation files in a web server. So I was looking if they persist the base_url  in a file or in the database just like Wordpress does but they do not. Its up to the developer if he will be based on the auto url detection mechanism(using also $_SERVER[] global php array). But also the right performance of this mechanism is based on the right web server configuration. So I was looking for the possible situations that the not uncommented $base_url line will cause a problem to the core mechanism or to a plugin.